# Need Order without shipping method

Tags: frontend

I ship world wide and would like to add shipping and tariff charges under a different system.
How can I take an order and leave Shipping to be deterrented. The buyer can pay for the whole order less shipping. We will email shipping Charges and tariffs for customers approval.
This is only on orders not served by UPS.

Can this be done?

Comment: virtual products avoid using shipping options, you can use that kind of product types. then you can send customer the shipping information.

Comment: The same product ships to both UPS and International. They are all Bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flat rate or table rate shipping method of zero dollars.  Rename the method to "Shipping to be charged later" or something to that effect.  You could set the method to show only for selected countries.

This would be simplest solution since you said virtual products are not an option.